# What is the right way to organize communication of two clients with one table?

Tags: sql, qt, postgresql, architecture, parallel-processing

I am using `PostgreSQL` as my database and `C++ with Qt` for my client. Several clients may connect to database at the same time and start editing one table. What is the right way to organize this process?

The last thing I have come up to is to edit cached table on client side, have separate table in database with last time table was modified and make some kind of `diff` procedure on commit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please avoid timestamp diff.

use row locking if you think you need it. use sequences that are derived from the database, query as frequently as you can while avoiding performance issues.

**edit:**

see the `SELECT FOR UPDATE` syntax for row locking options.

sequences are generated, guaranteed to be unique numerical values managed by the databse.  this is the layer you need to manage concurrency.

Comment: 1. Can I make table behave that way: user opens application — table is locked, closes — unlocked.

Comment: 2. What does "sequences that are derived from the database" mean? And how can they help me?

Comment: Thank you, SELECT FOR UPDATE is what i need. But here is another question: how can I use it with Qt models =)

Answer (score 0):

Or have a middle tier and a transaction layer to maintain ACID for you.

I don't think your design will scale very well.

Answer (score 0):

Read the [chapter 13, "Concurrency Control"](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/mvcc.html) from the manual.

Comment: As I understand row locking and concurrency control in general solves problem of simultaneous access to the same data. But my problem is problem of invalid data on client side when you edit table on your side but table was updated in database.